# How to Deploy Online a WebGL Build of Unity Game on the web?

Tags: html, unity-game-engine

I have some games that are builded in WebGL and want to have a link to give it for others to play online.
Is there any free website that provide us this service???

Comment: Itch.io might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have used itch.io and upload some web player build games.
But I want to say is there any way to upload WebGL build Games?

Answer (score 1):

Itch.io

1. Zip up your Unity3D WebGL build. The index.html file should be at the root of the zip file.
2. In https://itch.io/game/edit/ under "Kind of project" select "HTML"
3. Under "Uploads" upload your zip file.
4. After the upload is complete, under "Uploads" ensure you have "This file will be played in the browser" checked.
5. Scroll down and click "Save"

Answer (score 0):

GameDev.tv

The above site is specifically built to handle uploads from Unity3D including WebGL builds.